# Can't Hide List Menu With Jquery/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem in hiding a list menu generated dynamically with php. My browser didn't hide it. I am using Firefox; the code is like this:

```
<div id="groupstd">
<br />
<select style="text-align:center;" name="std3">
<option value="Select" selected="selected">Please Select Student.no#3</option>
<?php
$result=Connect();
if($result>0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo '<option value=$row[\'Roll#\'].\'i-\'.$row[\'Batch\']>$row[\'Roll#\'].\'i-\'.$row[\'Batch\']</option>';
  }
}?>
</select>
</div>
<div id="grpstd">
<br />
<select style="text-align:center;" name="std4" id="std4">
<option value="Select" selected="selected">Please Select Student.no#4</option>
<?php
$result=Connect();
if($result>0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo '<option value=$row[\'Roll#\'].\'i-\'.$row[\'Batch\']>$row[\'Roll#\'].\'i-\'.$row[\'Batch\']</option>';
  }
}?>
</select>
</div>
```

I am using JQuery to hide like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#grpstd').hide();
    $('#groupstd').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing this after the **dom** is ready as using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#grpstd, #groupstd').hide();//using two elements using one statement
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When are you trying to hide the divs? You will need to wait until at least the document is [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#grpstd').hide();
    $('#groupstd').hide();
});
```

Comment: I have Included Ready Function That's Only Part Of Code
But This Is Not Working

Comment: Do you have the jQuery library loaded properly? What do `$('#grpstd')` and `$('#groupstd')` look like in Firebug? To they each have one element? There are number of things that could be wrong, but unless you provide more information, all we can do is speculate.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#grpstd, #groupstd').hide();
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
  $('#grpstd, #groupstd').hide();
});
```

Comment: I have Included Ready Function That's Only Part Of Code But This Is Not Working

Comment: @user1375948 try this at the end of your body tag, i.e just before `</body>` or if this is within any separate JS file then include it just before `</body>` tag.